# Unable to get Validation Rule to work

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to create a validation rule in Salesforce that prevents a host Opportunity Record (ID-0125G000000GWLlQAO) Type from moving to a closed won stage (8. Deal Won) without the "Number of Listings" field being populated with a value greater than zero.  The Number of listings field is a formula field with the value being populated on the related Account Record.  I have tried so many iterations.  Heres the latest:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"),
    RecordTypeId = '0125G000000GWLlQAO',
    Number_of_Listings__c <= 0
)
```

I am not getting any syntax errors

Comment: I'd advise against hard-coding the record type id (or any id, really) in validation rules or formulas. If you've made the record type in a Sandbox and then deployed it to your production org, for example, the record type will have a different Id in production (until you refresh your sandbox(es), at which time it'll be the same Id as production). Using `RecordType.Name` or `RecordType.DeveloperName` is preferable.

Comment: Also, there seems to be a disconnect between the StageName you gave as an example (8. Deal Won) and the StageName included in your formula. Did you perhaps mean to use a combination of `IsClosed` and `IsWon` in this validation formula instead?

Comment: This works!  Thanks all :D  AND(
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "8. Deal Won"),
RecordType.Name = "Host",
Account.Number_of_Listings__c <= 0
)

Comment: As a sanity check, you should also look at the value of `Number_of_Listings__c` on the Opportunity you're testing this on (to make sure it isn't actually > 0 ). Is the Opportunity you're testing on related to an Account in the first place? If not, and if your formula is set to "treat blanks as blanks", then `null <= 0` would return false and prevent your validation rule from triggering.